# How to display the highest value in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem with the code I've written. I am trying to get the highest value of an array in the void function, but all I am getting in the compiler is the value of the 4th array, regardless of the other values. 
So currently if I input 40, 30, 20, 10 it is going to assign the value 10 as the highest. Could someone explain to me what it is I am doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

string divName[4] = { "Northeast", "Southeast", "Northwest", "Southwest" };

double getSales(string name)
{
    double Sales;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "Enter the quarterly sales for the " << name << " division: ";
        cin >> Sales;
        if (Sales != 0)
            break;
    }
    return Sales;
}

void findHighest(double sales[4])
{
    double highest = 0;
    int division = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if (sales[i] > highest);
        {

            highest = sales[i];
            division = i;
        }

    }
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "The " << divName[division] << " division had the highest sales this quarter." << std::endl << "Thier sales were $" << highest;
    cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    double sales[4];

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        sales[i] = getSales(divName[i]);
    }
        findHighest(&sales[0]);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question seems off topic because it's caused by a typo. See this statement `if (sales[i] > highest);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the extra semicolon in the comparison statement:

```
if (sales[i] > highest);  // <<< This semicolon
{
    highest = sales[i];
    division = i;
}
```

The program will make the comparison `sales[i] > highest` and then do nothing... After that it assigns sales[i] to highest whatever happens. Delete that semicolon and it works.

Comment: Yeah, it's working perfectly now. I can't believe I missed something as small as that. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
double getSales(string name)
{
    double Sales;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "Enter the quarterly sales for the " << name << " division: ";
        cin >> Sales;
        if (Sales != 0)
            break;
    }
    return Sales;
}
```

This code here only writes the last input into `Sales`. Store what you get from `cin` in an array?

Comment: That won't fix it- if you look at how he uses the return value he _does_ put that into an array. `Sales` is a local.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use 2 variables inside the findHighest function. It could be used with only one.

```
void findHighest(double sales[4])
{
    int maxIndex = 0;   

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (sales[maxIndex] < sales[i])
            maxIndex = i;
    }

    cout << std::endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "The " << divName[maxIndex] << " division had the highest sales this quarter." << std::endl << "Thier sales were $" << maxIndex;
    cout << std::endl;
}
```